# How to upload file to server at a specific time?

Tags: webserver, dreamweaver, cpanel, whm

For a long time now I have a retail web site that has certain pages that need to be uploaded at midnight.  For instance, there are often sales that start or end at midnight.  How can I go about having the server automatically post an updated version of an HTML page without having to wait for midnight to manually upload the file to the server?

I was thinking that there should be a way to put the file on the server but for the server to not replace the current version of the file with the new one until a certain time.  If that's not possible, or if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

Just in case you need to know:  I typically use Dreamweaver CS5.5, but also have used FileZila when needed.  As far as the server goes, it's a VPS that runs WHM and cPanel.  I'm willing to use a different program or install any special software that would help me out with this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Isn't it just a scheduled task that runs at midnight?

Answer (score 0):

You upload to a staging directory and write a cron job to run at midnight to copy the files from the staging directory to the target directories.  crontab -e will open an editor to edit the cron file and I think you want:

0 0 * * * cp /*.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip ipaul.  I've never used a staging directory before, and have never wrote a cron job before.  Can anyone either tell me how to do this, or provide me with a link to a good "how to" instruction?  Thanks so much!